# Is it possible to get non-contiguous slices from an ndarray?

Tags: matrix, indexing, rust

Is it possible to index columns in a Rust [`ndarray`](https://docs.rs/ndarray) matrix using a `Vec` rather than a `Slice` object? The only documentation I can find pertains to slicing using [contiguous columns](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html#indexing-and-slicing)

Specifically, I am trying to implement something like the following code in Python:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]])
idx = [0,1,2,4]
x[:, idx]
```

The outcome of `x[:, idx]` would be the subset of the matrix containing all rows and only columns described in `idx`, i.e., `[0,1,2,4]`.

I am currently using `ndarray` (as the title suggests) but I cannot find a way to subset on non-contiguous slices. For instance, you can pass `ndarray`, which can take a `Slice` with a `start`, `stop` and an `index`, but I cannot find a way to pass a list of columns that cannot be described using a `Slice` object.

For instance:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate ndarray;

fn main() {
    let mut x = array![[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]];
    let idx = vec![0, 1, 2, 4];
    // The following works as expected
    let y = x.slice(s![.., 0..2]);
    println!("{:?}", y);
    // This is conceptually what I would like to do but
    // It does not work.
    let y = x.slice(s![.., idx]);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The analogue of "advanced indexing" in Numpy is the [`ArrayBase::select()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.select) method:

```
use ndarray::{array, Axis};

fn main() {
    let x = array![[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]];
    let idx = vec![0, 1, 2, 4];
    println!("{}", x.select(Axis(1), &idx));
}
```

producing the output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5],
 [7, 8, 9, 11]]
```

Note that the resulting array is a copy of the selected elements (just as it is in Numpy).  Depending on your use case, you may not need the copy;  it's possible you can make do with just iterating over `idx` and using `x.slice(s![.., i])` for all `i` in `idx`.

Comment: Fantastic! thanks so much, Sven. I completely missed it in the docs. It's perhaps worth including in the "`ndarray` for NumPy users."

Comment: @mandy Yeah, it's not obvious on first glance.  I found it quickly by guessing its name – it's basically the same operation as `itertools.select()` in Python.